# Jolt - use value from parent as key

Tags: json, jolt

I have the below json and i want to take the value from the DataSetWriterId field, which is dynamic and use it as the key value, followed by a counter for each Body item.

```json
{
  "MessageType": "ua-data",
  "PublisherId": "1",
  "Messages": [
    {
      "DataSetWriterId": "key_07",
      "SequenceNumber": 2,
      "Payload": {
        "Data": [
          {
            "Type": 1,
            "Body": false
          },
          {
            "Type": 1,
            "Body": false
          },
          {
            "Type": 1,
            "Body": false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Likely better explained here by the required output:

```json
{
  "key_01": false,
  "key_02": false,
  "key_03": false
}
```

Comment: You're right, sorry, i had a longer json and tried to trim it down for the question here, but obviously i didnt do it for the output

Ive edited this now, hopefully it should be clearer. 3 booleans from the 3 body values

Comment: Btw, would you like to increment starting from the value of `DataSetWriterId`, eg. from zero ? If it was `key_04`, the expected result will be, key_05, key_06, key_07 , right ?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Always with a leading 0 unless it is double figures: key_10 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following transformation in which the incrementing starts from the value of `DataSetWriterId`, extracted after the underscore such as

```json
[
  { // determine where to start for incrementing
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Messages": {
        "*": {
          "DataSetWriterId": "=split('_',@(1,&))",
          "dsw0": "@(1,DataSetWriterId[0])",
          "dsw1": "@(1,DataSetWriterId[1])",
          "i_": "=toInteger(@(1,dsw1))",
          "i": "=intSum(@(1,i_),1)",
          "incr": "=intSum(@(1,i),i)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Messages": {
        "*": {
          "@Payload.Data": {
            "*": {
              "@2,incr": "&1.incr",
              "@2,dsw0": "&1.dsw0",
              "$": "&1.seq",
              "Body": "&1.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // increment the "seq" values by "incr" values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "seq": "=intSum(@(1,&),@(1,incr))",
        "seq_": "=toString(@(1,seq))",
        "dsw1": "=leftPad(@(1,seq_), 2, '0')"
      }
    }
  },
  { // determine keys and values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "dsw*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3.k"
          }
        },
        "Body": "&1.v"
      }
    }
  },
  { // concatenate the array key's components
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "k": "=join('_',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  { // match key-value pairs
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@v": "&1.@k"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

as an example if the input JSON has `"DataSetWriterId": "key_07"`, then you'll get the result as

```json
[
  {
    "key_08": false
  },
  {
    "key_09": false
  },
  {
    "key_10": false
  }
]
```